# Setting back global variables back to their default value

Tags: python, global-variables

In game,I have created some global variables whose value changes when a certain action occur.When I restart the game,I want their value to be set again to their initial value.

```
K= 0

def change():
  #change global variable 
  value
  global K
  K +=5
 def restart():
  #restarts game
```

I can change global variable value by equilazing it back to its original value.

```
K = 0
```

Is there any other way to do so,when there are lot of variables,I can't make them local.

Thanks for your help

Comment: As long as you do not use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt), the value of a variable in global namespace cannot be changed within a function

Comment: I know it,just forget to add it ,my bad

Comment: Write a function the declares and initialize all variables or use a `Settings` class with class or instance attributes instead of global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is to little sample code there to give you an example - but from what I can get you are trying to do, it is time to move on to use some Object Orientation.

Without resorting to anything more complex, you can have an object that acts as a namespace for the variables you need to acess across several functions.

Upon re-starting the game, simply create a new instance with all the initial values set for your state-keeping object.

Due to the way Python works, you can even set the default values as class attributes, and each time those are updated, the update will affect only the instance corresponding to the state of the ongoing game. By doing this you can use *one* global variable, holding the game state instance:

```py
class GameState:
   k = 0
   other_var = 0

def restart():
   global state
   state = GameState()

def change():
   ...
   state.k += 5
```

note that if you do this correctly, you set grounds for getting "for free"  a way to save and resume your game, to have more than one player, each player with a separate state, at once, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want the game to reset but rather to continue after a restart. For this you have to save the variables to files. While the code is running all variables and their values are stored in the RAM of your device. When the code stops running they are removed from the RAM. To store variables after the code stopped you have to store them to your harddrive. For that you can simply create a file and put everything in there.

For variables you should either use SQLite3 (Database) or JSON. If you only store some variables JSON should do it, but if you store large amounts of variables in a game (With large amount I mean for example every entity that exists in a world and every chest and so on), you should use a Database.

Comment: This is not at all what the OP meant: "When I restart the game,I want their value to be set again to their initial value."